# How to disable automatic mnemonics in a Qt application on KDE?

Tags: c++, qt, shortcut, kde-plasma

In any Qt application on KDE when I add a `QPushButton` in designer and check it's text by:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug()<<ui->pushButton->text();
}
```

The output is preceded by an `&` :

> &PushButton

This behavior does not exist on Windows. It seems that Qt applications on KDE automatically add shortcuts to all push buttons, which is not desired for me. I should note that the ampersands are not created by designer and you can not see them in the`.ui` file. Actually when the button is added to a widget, an `&` is placed somewhere in it's text.

Is it possible to disable automatic mnemonics of a Qt application in anyway?

Comment: This question is unclear. Does Qt Designer add these? Are they present in the .ui file? Are they added at runtime by Qt itself? You really need to make it clear.

Comment: @KubaOber The ampersands are not created by designer and you can not see them in .ui. It seems that when the button in added to a widget, an `&` is placed somewhere in it's text. Maybe that's the behavior of KDE.

Comment: Please put such clarifications in the question.

Comment: Went through this issue too... It occurred with plasma 5 and qt 5.5. No problem with kde 4 and qt 5.5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

KDEPlatformTheme plugin responsible for it.

A workaround is to add

```
[Development]
AutoCheckAccelerators=false
```

to `~/.config/kdeglobals`, which prevents KDE from automatically adding accelerators.

Related bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337491